# How to compose uint value from single bit (representing value1) and 23 bits (representing value2)?

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators

Some game that I currently reverse engineer store two values in 3 bytes.
`first value` size is `1 bit` and `second value` size is `23 bits`.

[0][000 0001 0001 0111 1001 0000] 0 stone, 71568 att

[1][000 0000 0010 1001 0000 0111] 1 stone, 10511 att

I found a way to read them like this:

```
    public byte AddedStonesCount
    {
        get
        {
            byte[] att_plus_stones_count_as_bytes = new byte[4];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(this.Data, 21, att_plus_stones_count_as_bytes, 0, 3);
            uint att_plus_stones_count = BitConverter.ToUInt32(att_plus_stones_count_as_bytes, 0);

            return (byte)(att_plus_stones_count >> 23);
        }
        set
        {
        
        }
    }
    public uint Attack
    {
        get
        {
            byte[] att_plus_stones_count_as_bytes = new byte[4];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(this.Data, 21, att_plus_stones_count_as_bytes, 0, 3);
            uint att_plus_stones_count = BitConverter.ToUInt32(att_plus_stones_count_as_bytes, 0);

            return att_plus_stones_count << 9 >> 9;
        }
        set
        {
        
        }
    }
```

But I also need a way to change them. That's where something always goes wrong for me.
I tried doing `att & 0x800000` to get `1 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000` added with attack, but strangely it give me 0 instead of the value I expect.

I doing some tests here:

```
        uint test = 0x80290F; //8399119 - here we store 1 stone added and 10511 attack power
        uint test_composition = 10511 & (0x800000); //this does not give me 8399119 :/

        BitArray ba = new BitArray(BitConverter.GetBytes(test));

        string test_original = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < ba.Length; i++)
            test_original += ba.Get(i) ? 1 : 0;

        uint att = test << 9 >> 9;

        BitArray ba_att = new BitArray(BitConverter.GetBytes(att));
        string test_att = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < ba_att.Length; i++)
            test_att += ba_att.Get(i) ? 1 : 0;

        uint stones = test >> 23;
```

Help...

For example, when pet has attack = `10511` and amount of stones added = `1`, then end value should be `8399119`.

Comment: What's the end value you're trying to end up with? I have no idea what stones or pet attacks (is `att` the same as `pet attack`?) are. I think if you just focus on the question of bit manipulation and be consistent with your terminology, it will make this question a lot clearer.

Comment: @itsme86 - I put example in the end of my question.

Comment: Oh I see. It looks like you should just be using OR (`|`) instead of AND (`&`).

Comment: `(stones << 23) | attack`?

Comment: @KlausGütter - thank you, this is working. Make it as answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set bit#23 according to stones (0 or 1) and the bits#0...22 according to attack, use the bitwise OR operator:

```
(stones << 23) | attack
```